# is 'covering family' order decidable?

Tags: set-theory

The theory of the subset relation $(M,\subseteq)$ is decidable (see [Set theoretetic mereology by J.Hampkins](http://jdh.hamkins.org/set-theoretic-mereology/)); what can be said about mereology once removed, i.e.  the "covering family relation"

> $X \leq Y$ iff for each $x$ in $X$ there is $y$ in $Y$ such that $x$ is a subset of $y$ ?
>
> $X \leq_\kappa Y$ iff each union of $<\kappa$ elements of $X$ is contained in some union of $<\kappa$ elements of $Y$, up to $<\kappa$ elements, i.e.
>
> ```
>  for each $X' \subset X$ such that $|X'|<\kappa$, there exists $Y' \subset Y$ 
>  such that $|Y'| < \kappa$ and
>  $| \cup X' \setminus \cup Y' | < \kappa$
> ```

Are these relations decidable? How does it vary with the underlying model of set theory? Does it depend on $\kappa$ (provided $\kappa$ is regular)?

The preorder $\leq_\kappa$ lets one talk about some large cardinals
($\kappa$ is measurable iff the preorder $\leq_\kappa$ is not dense), and, 
in a way, the covering numbers of PCF theory.